# Error al crear procedimiento almacenado en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy creando un procedimiento almacenado en phpmyadmin el cual se describe a continuación:

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE 'OperacionEntradaVehiculos' (
varMarca varchar(100),
varModelo varchar(100),
varAnioVehiculo varchar(4),
varChasis varchar(100),
varPlaca varchar(100),
varPeso float,
varColorVehiculo varchar(20),
varTipoVehiculo varchar(100)
)

BEGIN
    IF (varId=0) THEN
        INSERT INTO vehiculos (marca, modelo, anioVehiculo, chasis, placa, peso, colorVehiculo, tipoVehiculo) VALUES ( varMarca, varModelo, varAnioVehiculo, varChasis, varPlaca, varPeso, varColorVehiculo, varTipoVehiculo);

        SELECT @@IDENTIFY AS 'Identify';

      ELSE
        UPDATE vehiculos
            SET   marca=varMarca,  modelo=varModelo, anioVehiculo=varAnioVehiculo, chasis=varChasis, placa=varPlaca, peso=varPeso, colorVehiculo=varColorVehiculo, tipoVehiculo=varTipoVehiculo  WHERE id=varId;
      END IF;
  END
```

al ejecutar el código me arroja el siguiente error:

> #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '"OperacionEntradaVehiculos" (
> varMarca varchar(100),
> varModelo varchar(100),
> ' en la linea 1

Comment: El nombre del PA no necesita comillas en su nombre, prueba quitandolas, por otro lado si por alguna razón necesitas usarlas entonces deben ser las *backticks* \`

Comment: Aquí casi al final puedes comprobar la sintaxis adecuada https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probablemente es porque te sobran las comillas simples en el nombre del procedure. Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
CREATE DEFINER='root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE OperacionEntradaVehiculos(
```

Comment: Efectivamente ese era el error, gracias